# Power series solution of $x^2y'=y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Not able to understand its solution. Its final answer is $Y=ce^{-1/x}$. I have tried but no able to reach the solution.

Comment: Use an [integrating factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor) of  $$M(x)=e^{{\int _{{s_{0}}}^{{x}}P(s)ds}}$$ with $P(x) = -\frac1{x^2}$

Comment: Note that $e^{-1/x}$ has no power series around $x=0$.

Comment: If $y=\sum_{n\leq0}a_nx^{-n}$, then $x^2\left(\sum_{n\leq0}a_nx^{-n}\right)'=\sum_{n\leq0} -na_nx^{-(n-1)}=\sum_{n\leq0} a_nx^{-n}$. Therefore, $-na_n=a_{n-1}$. It follows that $a_n=(-1)^na_0/n!$. Therefore, $y=a_0e^{-1/x}$.

Comment: @orole I think this must be the intended solution. However it only holds when $(\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nx^n)'=\sum_{n\ge 0}(a_nx^n)'$, that is, if the last power series converges uniformly.

Comment: @Masacroso Keep thinking. Maybe you will get to it.

Comment: Nice @orole do you mean for the indice n $ \ge 0$ or am I missing something ...

Comment: How to solve by power series

Comment: @orole $y=\sum_{n\leq0}a_nx^{-n}=a_0\sum_{n\leq0}(-1)^nx^{-n}/n!=a_0\sum_{n\leq0}(-\frac 1 x)^n/n!= ........$  I don't get it ...why the indice n is $ \le 0$ here for the exponential ? And what s the meaning for n! if $n\le 0$ ?

Answer (score 1):

$x^2 y' = y \to \dfrac{y'}{y}=\dfrac{1}{x^2}\to\dfrac{dy}{y}=\dfrac{dx}{x^2}$ 
    (Note that $y'=\dfrac{dy}{dx}$)

We now integrate from both sides:

$\int{\dfrac{dy}{y}}=\int{\dfrac{dx}{x^2}}\to ln(|y|)=\dfrac{x^{-1}}{-1}+c$

Take an exponent from both sides:

$|y|=e^{-1/x+c}=e^{-1/x}e^{c}=ce^{-1/x}$

(Note that because $c$ is undetermined, there is no difference between $e^c$ or $c$)

Finally, the equation will be as below where c is a real number:

$y=ce^{-1/x}$

Comment: How to solve by power series method