# Power series solution of differential equation $x^2y'=y$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Can we solve this DE using power series method?
a power series solution of  $$x^2y'=y$$
I know it can be solved by variable separation $$y=ce^{-1/x}$$ but when i try to solve it by the method of power series it leads to $$y = c_1x$$
this was asked before but no satisfying asnwer was given [Power series solution of $x^2y'=y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2645918/power-series-solution-of-x2y-y) .

Comment: The solution necessarily satisfies $y(0) = 0$. So, your $y = ce^{-1/x}, x\neq 0$ only admits a Taylor series at $0$ if $c=0$, because otherwise it's not even continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$x=0$ is singular point. Let $x=\frac1t$. Then $y'=\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}=-t^2\frac{dy}{dt}$ and the equation becomes $\frac{dy}{dt}=-y$ with the solution $y=ce^{-t}$ which can be obtained by series method:

Let $y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nt^n.$ Then $y'=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nt^{n-1}.$ The given equation $y'+y=0$ becomes
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nt^{n-1}+\sum_{\color{purple}{n=0}}^{\infty}a_\color{purple}{n}t^\color{purple}{n}=0$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nt^{n-1}\sum_{\color{purple}{n-1=0}}^{\infty}a_\color{purple}{n-1}t^\color{purple}{n-1}=0$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nt^{n-1}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n-1}t^{n-1}=0$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(na_n+a_{n-1})t^{n-1}=0$$
Since $t$ takes many values, we set $na_n+a_{n-1}=0$ for $n\geq 1$. We obtained so called  the [indical equation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IndicialEquation.html) of the given differential equation. This is a reccurence equation. We need an initial value $a_0=c\in\Bbb R$. Then by induction we find that $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}c.$ Hence
$$y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}ct^n=y=c\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-t)^n}{n!}=ce^{-t}$$
and
$$y=ce^{-\frac1x}.$$

Comment: @modfun I hardly remember sophomore days and Shepley L. Ross. Somebody borrowed my book did not return.